how to get all classname in scss file by PsiTreeUtil.findChildrenOfType
i'm trying to write a plugins for webstorm , i want to get all css classname by
 private void addCompletions(@NotNull CompletionResultSet result, StylesheetFile stylesheetFile) {
                var  imports = PsiTreeUtil.findChildrenOfType(stylesheetFile , CssClassImpl.class);
                System.out.println(imports.stream().map(e->e.getName()).toList());
}


scss file
.logo-head {
  color: red;
  &-color-profile {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .demo-foo {
    color: aliceblue;
  }
}

but i just get ["logo-head" , "demo-foo"] , the "logo-head-color-profile" is lose ;
i hope get all classname in scss file ;
